# StringBuilder Null Checks for MySQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql, nullable, stringbuilder, ternary-operator

I've got a non-static class which includes 14 properties which are publicly accessible. The class will also have three methods for returning an Update, Insert and Delete MySQL query (as a string) using values from the instance of the class. Some of the properties are nullable, so I need to check this before creating the MySQL query.

At the moment, I'm going about it this way:

```
public string GetNewString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO `dbname`.`tablename` (`OrderID`, `Code`, `Supplier`, `Unit`, `From`, `To`, `StockType`, `ItemsOrdered`, `QtyNewItems`, `PerNewItems`, `ArrivedDate`, `CompletedDate`, `Notes`, `OrderDate`) VALUES (");
            //PK & not nullable, so no check
            sb.Append($"'{this.OrderID}', ");

            if (this.Code.ToString().Length.Equals(0))
            {
                sb.Append("NULL, ");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append($"'{this.Code}', ");
            }

            if (this.Supplier.ToString().Length.Equals(0))
            {
                sb.Append("NULL, ");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append($"'{this.Supplier}', ");
            }
```

**My question is, is there an easier way of doing this without an If / Else loop for every single property?** I've tried using ternary operators, but it didn't much like it. There's nothing wrong (at least from what I can see) with the way I'm doing it now, except for bloating the method.

Also, I'm not the best or most experienced with C#, so sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: Do you absolutely *have* to include the values within a SQL string? I would strongly advise you to use parameterized SQL instead. It will protect you from SQL injection attacks, avoid conversion errors and make the code cleaner as well.

Comment: You are doing this all wrong. Never use any kind of string concatenation to build SQL queries. You have just condamened yourself to the database programmer's hell. There is only one way. Parameterized queries

Comment: _"My question is, is there an easier way of doing this without an If / Else loop for every single property?"_ 1. if/else is _not_ a "loop" 2. Yes there is a better way (see comments above): [Parameterized SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb738521(v=vs.100)).

Comment: Oh Lord, first post and I've embarrassed myself with a security flaw? I knew about SQL Injection attacks but didn't bare that in mind whatsoever since it was a small internal application which only about three people will use. I'll look into parameterized SQL queries instead.

Comment: Preventing SQL Injection is only one benefit of using Parameterized Queries. And I don't think you embarrassed yourself. Didn't we all start at some point? People tend to forget their own "rookie" days.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized queries help you to avoid sql injection, but you use them not just for this. They help you write better code (no missing quotes or doubling the existing quotes in values, no parsing problem with decimals and doubles) and more readable code.

Just a note, if you want to insert a null value, you use the DBNull.Value.

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO `dbname`.`tablename` 
                (`OrderID`, `Code`, `Supplier`, `Unit`, `From`, `To`, 
                 `StockType`, `ItemsOrdered`, `QtyNewItems`, `PerNewItems`, 
                 `ArrivedDate`, `CompletedDate`, `Notes`, `OrderDate`) 
                 VALUES 
                 (@OrderID, @Code, @Supplier, @Unit, @From, @To, 
                  @StockType, @ItemsOrdered, @QtyNewItems, @PerNewItems, 
                  @ArrivedDate, @CompletedDate, @Notes, @OrderDate)";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = orderID;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code) ? DBNull.Value : (object)code) ;

---- and so on for all other parameters, no need to convert them to strings -----
```

However, if your main concern is the simplicity of your code (IE less is better) then probably you should look at some kind of ORM that hide all the boilerplate code of ADO.NET. For example, using the free ORM [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) (a lightweight ORM library) you could simply write this

```
MyOrderClass orderInstance = this;

using(IDbConnection cnn = GetYourOpenConnectionFromThisMethod())
{
     string query = " --- as above --- ";
     int result = cnn.Execute(query, orderInstance);

}
```

The only caveat here is the fact that your MyOrderClass properties should have the same name of your database fields.